# How can 2 different classes point to the same datatable name

Tags: c++

I need to initialize an object in a method without specifying the class from where the object is. Can I do that?

can someone give me an example?

EDIT:

```
MyClass{
...};
MySecondClass
{...
};
void method(*object); //how to write correct??
{..}
MyClass *x= new MyClass();
MySecondClass *y= new MySecondClass();
method(x);
method(y);
```

Comment: Please explain your question a bit more! Are you initializing an object or creating an object?

Comment: Could you give some pseudocode example to illustrate what you want exactly?

Comment: Can you give me and example? The question is not very clear.

Comment: I would like to do something like this void method(*object); //and not MyClass* object;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use templates.

```
template <typename T>
void method(T* object) {
   // do stuff with the object, whose real type will be substituted for `T`
}
```

Templates are a bit complex, so read the chapter in your C++ book on them for more information.

Comment: and wbat to add in template? Can you please...rewrite my code using your idea?

Comment: @linuxx: What to add? Whatever you want your code to do. I could rewrite all your code for you, but my fee is $150/hr.

Comment: i just wanted to tell me how to add in the template the classes I need:)

Comment: See my answer if you want to know what to add :-)

Comment: @linuxx: Read the chapter in your C++ book about templates.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're looking for an interface.  You would define an interface that fits the needs of whatever it is that your method is doing.

```
class MyInterface 
{
    public:
    virtual void doSomething1() = 0;
    virtual void doSomething2() = 0;
};


class MyObject : public MyInterface
{
    public:
    void doSomething1()
    {
        // Code here
    }

    void doSomething2()
    {
        // Code here
    }
};
```

It's somewhat unclear exactly the situation you have b/c you haven't shown any code, but make the method you want to call part of a class. (if it isn't already)

```
class ClassWithMethod
{
    public:
    ClassWithMethod(MyInterface &myI)
        :x(myI)
    {
    }

    void methodYouUseInjectedObject()
    {
        // Code
        x.doSomething1();
        // More code
    }

    private:
    MyInterface &x;

};
```

Then in you application code where you instantiate the ClassWithMethod, you would "inject" the concrete type of the object you want called.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    MyObject myObject;

    ClassWithMethod classMethod(myObject);

    // Call the method that will use the injected object.
    classMethod.methodYouUseInjectedObject();
    return 1;
}
```

**EDIT: (based on updated question)**

If you want to create a method that can take two different (and unrelated) objects, but the use the same method signatures you can use a template.

```
 class ClassWithMethod
    {
        public:
        template <class T>
        void methodYouUseInjectedObject(T object)
        {
            T.doSomething();
        }

    };
```

This is similar to my approach above except that you do not need to derive your different objects off an interface.

Comment: His `MyClass` isn't related to his `MySecondClass`. Still, this is a possible approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a template.

```
template<typename T>
void method(T object) {
    object.doSomething()
}
```